# Reset nos campos input após submit com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Fazendo o envio dos valores dos campos input através de JQuery para uma página PHP consigo efetuar a ação sem dar "refresh" na página principal porém, não consigo fazer com que os campos input voltem a ficar "vazios"?!? Como aplicar então o "reset" após a submissão?

**HTML:**

```
<div id='status'></div>
<form id="new_user" method="post" action="javascript:func()">
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
    <br />
    <input type='text' name='mail' id='mail'/>
    <br /><input type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
    <br /><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='enviar'/>
    <br />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#status{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 150px;
    left:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: red;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function($) {
  // Quando o formulário for enviado, essa função é chamada
  $("#new_user").submit(function() {
    // Colocamos os valores de cada campo em uma váriavel para facilitar a manipulação
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var mail = $("#mail").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    // Exibe mensagem de carregamento
    $("#status").html("<center><img src='core/img/loader.gif' alt='Enviando'/></center>");
    // Fazemos a requisão ajax com o arquivo envia.php e enviamos os valores de cada campo através do método POST
    $.post('#', {name: name, mail: mail, password: password }, function(resposta) {
        // Quando terminada a requisição
        // Exibe a div status
        $("#status").slideDown();
        // Se a resposta é um erro
        if (resposta != false) {
          // Exibe o erro na div
          $("#status").html(resposta);
        } 
        // Se resposta for false, ou seja, não ocorreu nenhum erro
        else {
          // Exibe mensagem de sucesso
          $("#status").html("<center>Cadastro realizado com sucesso!</center>");
          // Limpando todos os campos
          $("#name").val("");
          $("#mail").val("");
          $("#password").val("");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/U5up4/)**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Limpando todos os campos de um formulário:

```
$(':input','#form')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
```

Redefinindo os valores iniciais de um formulário:

```
$('#form')[0].reset();
```

Agora basta escolher uma das soluções e adicionar após o seu `$.post()`.

### [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/faTq9/)

- [Fonte das técnicas de limpeza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364313/1683070)

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Seu primeiro exemplo não funcionou comigo?!? más o segundo ficou perfeito só uma nota: ele ficou dentro de else. Grato pela ajuda :)

Comment: @LauroMoraes Se você abrir o JSFiddle da resposta ele está funcionando. Você não esqueceu de trocar o ID do formulário?

Comment: Troquei sim...mas não faço ideia do pq não funcionou aqui comigo. Já o segundo exemplo (redefinindo valores iniciais) funcionou perfeitamente. Após o retorno positivo dos dados e a resposta. Mais uma vez grato pela ajuda :)

Comment: Como faz para resetar todos os campos da página?

Comment: @Dr.G O segundo trecho de código mostra como resetar um form. Se tiver vários forms em uma página, faça o reset em todos eles ao invés de em um só. Se precisar de mais detalhes, sugiro fazer uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta anterior para deixar a função mais genérica usando apenas javascript, segue o código que funciona para outros tipos de input.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "text") {
        elements[i].value = "";
    } 
    else if (elements[i].type == "radio"){
        elements[i].checked = false;  
    }
    else if (elements[i].type == "checkbox"){
        elements[i].checked = false;
    }
    else if (elements[i].type == "select") {
        elements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método nativo do JavaScript `reset()` para redefinir o formulário inteiro ao seu estado padrão.

Exemplo:

```
$("#myForm")[0].reset();
```

**Nota:** Isto não pode repor certos campos, como type = "hidden".

Amesma coisa pode ser realizada utilizando trigger `jQuery()`:

```
$("#myForm").trigger("reset");
```

tente pesquisar um pouco no stackoverflow, existem vários topicos abordando o mesmo

[Reset Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

Use o seguinte:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].type == "text") {
    elements[i].value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou aqui...e tenho 3 campos, um password e dois text

Answer (score -1):

> Usando JQuery

`$('#form').each(function () {
      this.reset();
});`

Answer (score -2):

Usando jQuery você pode optar por:

```
$("#form").trigger("reset");
```

Comment: A resposta é ok, porem já existe uma [resposta de 2015](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46587/3774) nessa pergunta indicando essa possibilidade.