# Limpar inputs dentro de form depois de enviar a mensagem

Tags: jquery

Tenho um `form` com alguns `input`, e quero que depois que o cliente envie o formulário, ele limpe os campos.

Meu HTML:

```js
function contatoForm() {

  if ($.trim($('#contatoNome').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoNome').val()) == 'Nome') alert('Informe seu nome!');
  else if ($.trim($('#contatoEmail').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoEmail').val()) == 'E-mail') alert('Informe seu e-mail!');
  else if ($.trim($('#contatoTelefone').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoTelefone').val()) == 'Telefone') alert('Informe seu telefone!');
  else if ($.trim($('#contatoCidade').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoCidade').val()) == 'Cidade') alert('Informe a sua cidade!');
  else if ($.trim($('#contatoUf').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoUf').val()) == 'UF') alert('Informe a Unidade Federativa!');
  else if ($.trim($('#contatoMensagemForm').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#contatoMensagemForm').val()) == 'Mensagem') alert('Informe a mensagem!');
  else {
    $.post('carregamentos/contato.php',
      $('#contatoFormulario').serialize(),
      function(abc) {
        alert('Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
      }
    );
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="contatoFormulario" id="contatoFormulario" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return contatoForm();">
  <input type="text" id="contatoNome" name="contatoNome" value="nome*" placeholder="nome*" />
  <input type="text" id="contatoEmail" name="contatoEmail" value="e-mail*" placeholder="e-mail*" />
  <input type="text" id="contatoTelefone" name="contatoTelefone" value="telefone" placeholder="telefone" />
  <input class="grid_325 f-left" type="text" id="contatoCidade" name="contatoCidade" value="cidade" placeholder="cidade" />
  <input class="grid_145 f-right" type="text" id="contatoUf" name="contatoUf" value="UF" placeholder="UF" />
  <textarea type="text" id="contatoMensagemForm" name="contatoMensagemForm" value="mensagem*" placeholder="mensagem*"></textarea>
  <div class="contatoFormularioPreenchimento">(*) Preenchimento obrigat&oacute;rio.</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="checkboxG5" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked" value="news" />
  <label for="checkboxG5" class="css-label radGroup1 contatoLabel margin-top-20">Quero receber as novidades por e-mail.</label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <span id="enviaText" class="saibaMaisFlecha f-left margin-top-30 d-block cp">Enviar</span>
  <input id="envia" type="submit" class="flechaPreta f-left margin-top-25 cp margin-left-10" value="" />
  <input style="display:none" type="reset" id="limpa" />
</form>
```

Eu tentei fazer com

```
$( "#envia" ).click(function() {
    $("#limpa").click();
});
```

Fazer o mesmo clique que envia o formulário, já limpar os campos, só que na real, ele tá limpando antes de enviar, então o meu JS que faz a validação dos campos, diz que eles não estão preenchidos, qual seria a melhor forma de limpar os campos assim que enviar o formulário?

Comment: Possivel duplicata? -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23539/129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simule o clique no botão após o formulário ser enviado pelo ajax.

```
$.post('carregamentos/contato.php',
  $('#contatoFormulario').serialize(),
  function(abc) {
    alert('Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
    $('#limpa').click(); // Aqui o form já foi submetido, então pode ser limpo
  }
);
```

Comment: Exato, tinha que ser depois do `alert` mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode utilizar:

```
$('#form_id_teste input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
})
```

ou:

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

Fontes ou referências da mesma pergunta: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery