# Como resetar todos os dados de um formulário se o usuário voltar a página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário que após ser submetido apresenta o resultado numa segunda página, tipo:

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="form.php">
<input name='nome' id='nome'>
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>
```

E no `form.php` algo como:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
echo "O nome é $nome";
```

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23539/reset-nos-campos-input-ap%C3%B3s-submit-com-jquery) está respondido como fazer para resetar os dados quando a requisição é processada na mesma página, mas preciso que os dados que foram preenchidos sejam completamente zerados se o usuário voltar a página pelo botão do navegador ou usando o teclado. Tentei:

```
<script>
    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
</script>
```

Mas não funcionou. O que preciso é que se o usuário voltar a página, o campo não esteja mais preenchido. O formulário tem vários tipos de campos (select, input, checkbox,radio), e preciso resetar todos.

Li várias questões no SOen, mas devido à barreira da língua fiquei até na dúvida sobre isso é mesmo possível.

É possível? Como?

Comment: Se for post se você voltar vai perguntar pra você reenviar o formulário. Resolvi isso enviando só por ajax e ao enviar o formulário, gravar no histórico a página do formulário. Você voltar e ele recarrega a pagina anterior. Vou procurar e te passo aqui o código.

Comment: Não @WillianCoqueiro, acho que vc tá confundindo... quando vc volta o navegador não pergunta nada.... O que o navegador pergunta é quando  o user dá F5 num form que já foi enviado p.ex. ou quando usa um JS/Jquery pra avisar que voltar da página do formulário (ainda não enviado) irá perder os dados e tal... No caso o que preciso é apagar os dados inseridos quando o user **voltar com o botão do navegador** (ou pelo teclado), depois de ter dado submit...

Comment: Depende do navegador. Mais pode usar o ajax ué já resove então. Captura os campos pelo JavaScript e reseta antes de enviar. Da certinho. ’$('form').submit(function(){     $(this)[0].reset(); });’

Comment: Não estou usando ajax, não daria certo pra mim... mas agradeço pela força...

Comment: Vai ter que usar JavaScript. E você não pode resetar antes de enviar esse formulário. Você pode usar JavaScript pra alterar o histórico após enviado na próxima página. Funciona perfeitamente também.

Comment: Sim @WillianCoqueiro, acho que funcionaria mesmo! Rola uma resposta com exemplo? Valeu!

Comment: Uso assim: `window.history.replaceState(msg, "Prefeitura Municipal ???????????", "index.php");` No seu caso deve-se usar após enviar a requisição. Problema que dessa maneira, ele vai excluir todo histórico que vc percorreu no host e deixar somente este. Pra mim resolveu para inibir o usuário a voltar, caso ele volte, sempre ira para a pagina inicial. Tem uma maneira de alterar o histórico de uma pagina no caso pode ser a anterior, mas não lembro porque não deu certo. Mas se este não resolver seu caso, de uma procurada por: Alterar histórico com JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo, mas quando o navegador volta, não recarrega os scripts, então é necessário um meio de dispará-lo.

Utilizando o evento `onpageshow` deve ser possível disparar tal evento. Não testei mas deve funcionar:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
   $('#myForm')[0].reset();
})
```

Comment: Acabei de testar e deu certo.

Comment: Oi Edson, aqui não deu certo, testei no Chrome e continuam aparecendo os campos preenchidos...

Comment: Nao pode estar dentro do $(window).load(), tentou fora dele?

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra opção é utilizar o `autocomplete` para `off`, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="nome_do_input">
```

---

**Usando `autocomplete="on"`, padrão:**

[image]

---

**Usando `autocomplete="off"`:**

[image]

Comment: Então, +1, mas olha só, no meu caso são algumas centenas de campos (inclusive dei uma pesquisada e acho que não funciona para select e textarea né...) e eu já uso jQuery... e não seria muito código pra incluir em todos os campos, ao invés de um script pequeno...? Neste caso não vale a pena usar só o script acima? Estou perguntando porque não sei mesmo... De outro lado vi no https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp que esta tag é compatível com browsers antigos... então gostaria se possível saber se você acha que é melhor no caso eu usar a função ou então mudar todas as tags?

Comment: Eu tenho estas dúvidas, mas a resposta foi boa, eu não conhecia a tag, e vai ser útil pra outras coisas ctz... valeu ae, vou shippar +100 de rep! Abraços.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta é melhor do que usar um reset ao carregar a página, me parece mais segura. Dito isso, nada te impede de usar ambos, né?

Comment: Como assim mais segura @cav_dan?

Comment: Em relação a ser compatível com mais navegadores e ser mais garantida de continuar funcionando a longo prazo. Mas, enfim, opinião minha.

Comment: Ok @Daniel, entendi. Valeu.